# How to update a UI element multiple times while in an event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have an event handler on a button that runs some lines of code. All the code does is run bubble sort on a list but also does some changes to some rectangles on a canvas. My problem is those changes only appear once it has exited the event handler. A similar question has been asked before however that only does one change instead of multiple in concession [UI update in WPF elements event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346088/ui-update-in-wpf-elements-event-handlers).
This is a similar goal to what I'm trying to achieve. [image]

If you're interested in what exactly the code is:

```
private void Run_btt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Key hold = new Key();
        var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
        double hold2, hold3;
        //for inside a for loop(bubble sort)
        for (int i = 0; i < Sequence.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Sequence.Count-i-1; c++)
            {
                //changes the colour of the 2 that are being compared
                Sequence[c].shape.Fill =(Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF00");
                Sequence[c+1].shape.Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF00");
                //pause for a bit so that you can see what the algorithm is doing
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
                if (Sequence[c].Value > Sequence[c + 1].Value)
                {
                    // swap the 2 rectangles
                    hold2 = Canvas.GetLeft(Sequence[c].shape);
                    hold3 = Canvas.GetLeft(Sequence[c + 1].shape);
                    hold = Sequence[c];
                    Sequence[c] = Sequence[c + 1];
                    Sequence[c + 1] = hold;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(Sequence[c].shape, hold2);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(Sequence[c + 1].shape, hold3);
                }
                //set colour back to normal
                Sequence[c].shape.Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(Sequence[c].Colour);
                Sequence[c + 1].shape.Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(Sequence[c + 1].Colour);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry if this question is too vague or not enough detail but I don't know much about this topic and really just starting out.

Comment: Declare the Click handler async, like `private async void Run_btt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` and replace `Thread.Sleep()` by `await Task.Delay()`. Never call `Thread.Sleep` in the UI thread. As an alternative to async/await, use a DipatcherTimer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It now works. I thought it would've been really complicated!

Comment: Until `async` came along, it would have been really complicated.  The UI won't update until the event handler returns control to the dispatcher.  In pre-Async times, that occurred at the end of the event handler.  When you put the `Sleep` in your handler, it slowed things down, but still only returned control at the end of the handler.  When you `await` something, the event handler gives back control to the dispatcher until the awaited thing completes.  This allows the UI a chance to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting @Clemens comment as answer.

If you give the method the `async` like:

```
public void async methodname()
```

and then once you need to update the UI you add:

```
await Task.Delay(1);
```

This will act like break point in your code that will update the UI with the changes you made. The 1 represents how long in millisecond the delay will be.